# How to get project URL within the application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to obtain my project URL so that I create a link to another section of my site when say for example new content is added I can append this location onto it.

Is there a way I can obtain this address

> http://localhost:56672/ or http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating links manually you should just use a relative URL instead of absolute. So instead of:

```
http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/some/link/here
```

Use this:

```
/some/link/here
```

The browser will automatically fill in the hostname.

If you are linking to an action method, then you should be using [`Url.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) or [`Html.ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: I want to store the link. Context: new content added which would lie in the notifications for the user. The user can click on this to access that content

Comment: And what difference does that make?

Comment: I want to save it to my database, if i save the string as "/some/link/here" will this automatically point in that direction if used as a href in the view?